# server mysql v3 , mysqldump v5 on remote

Tags: mysql

- Main server with mysql 3.22.20a
- mysqldump (mysql v.5) on remote server

mysqldump (v5) generates an error:

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute '/*!40100 SET @@SQL_MODE='MYSQL323' */':
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax near '40100 SET
>   @@SQL_MODE='MYSQL323' */' at line 1 (1064)

or

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute '/*!40100 SET @@SQL_MODE='' */': You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax near '40100 SET @@SQL_MODE='' */' at line
>   1 (1064)

How to make a dump of the database remotely?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL version 3.22 is a very old MySQL and the syntax is quite different. I think you'll need to install a mysqldump of the same version to succeed. If possible, then, consider upgrading.